# Hide and show elements when no data is returned by Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following html in my Angular app:

```
<div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="Type in Types">
            <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
                <div class="class1" ng-click="Method1(Type.Id, Type.Desc)">
                    <div class="white-text">
                        <img id="img_{{Type.Id}}" ng-src="./Images/{{Type.Desc}}" alt="{{Type.Desc}}" />
                        <h3>{{Type.Desc}}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

  </div>
```

The above does its job displaying all the items in `Types`

Now I want to display a textbox and a button whenever there are no elements in `Types`. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<div class="row">
        <div ng-if=" Types == null || Types.length == 0">
           <!-- Your textbox / input button here-->
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="Type in Types">
            <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
                <div class="class1" ng-click="Method1(Type.Id, Type.Desc)">
                    <div class="white-text">
                        <img id="img_{{Type.Id}}" ng-src="./Images/{{Type.Desc}}" alt="{{Type.Desc}}" />
                        <h3>{{Type.Desc}}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row" ng-show="Types">
        <div ng-repeat="Type in Types">
            <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
                <div class="class1" ng-click="Method1(Type.Id, Type.Desc)">
                    <div class="white-text">
                        <img id="img_{{Type.Id}}" ng-src="./Images/{{Type.Desc}}" alt="{{Type.Desc}}" />
                        <h3>{{Type.Desc}}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

  </div>

<div ng-show="!Types">Button and Textbox go here</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-show="Types == null"> Button and textbox go here</div>
```